# Displaying the output in console in VS for C code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012

I switched to VS Express 2012 for Windows Desktop from Turbo C (which is a terrible compiler) for writing C code. It is working fine, but the output is being displayed in a pop up commandline like window.I want the output in the "output window" which is at the bottom of VS ,which usually happens in VS.

I took the following steps.

1. Created an empty project
2. Changed the extension to c
3. Under the compile as option, changed it to compile as c.

C programs are working fine. Also, its not recognizing `getch()` though `getchar` is available

Comment: The only thing that displays in the Visual Studio output window while your program is running is OutputDebugString.

Comment: getch() was deprectaed a long time ago

Comment: The VS itself pauses the console screen after the output, there is no need of `getch()` or `getchar()`

Comment: You have just started working on VS, so try researching on various menu options, try to find their purpose by Googling, I hope this way you will find solution to your this problem also.

Comment: @Nishant ,it wont. You need to write getchar() or some other function to retain the console.

Comment: **Don't be hatin' on Turbo C.**   It may not be up to snuff by modern standards, but it was absolutely revolutionary at the time.   It created the modern IDE.  Even the newest Visual Studio versions take a lot of their form from the Turbo C.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>
#define ConsoleDebugPrintf(format, ...) \
    do { \
        char buf[512]; \
        snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, format, __VA_ARGS__); \
        OutputDebugString(buf); \
    } while (false);
```

You can use this macro just like printf. Maybe make `buf` bigger if you want.